# Proving $|EF|=|CF|$ in cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ with $|BC|=|CD|<2|AC|$ where $|AF|=|AC|$, $|CF|=|BC|$ and $E$ is intersection of diagonals.

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic (possibly self-intersecting) quadrilateral, such that $|BC|=|CD|<2|AC|$. Label intersection of its diagonals $E$. Let $F$ be a such point, that $|AF|=|AC|$ and $|CF|=|BC|$. Show that $|EF|=|CF|$.

[image: Diagram of the situation]

I don't need full answer, any hint would be greatly appreciated.